# Display_rotate=3 only filling half screen Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: pi-4

I have an issue such that when I rotate my screen to portrait with Display_rotate=3, the raspberry pi only fills the bottom half of the screen.

Comment: Welcome to SE Raspberry Pi! It would have been a bit more in the style of this website if you had answered your own question with 'Your Answer'.

Comment: To keep with our formatting here, I have edited your question to just be a question, and posted your answer as an answer below. Of course, it is your answer and not mine, so if you'd like, you can post your answer below again and I will remove mine.

Answer (score 2):

### OP posted his answer as an edit to his question, so I have edited it and moved the answer here:

After some searching and looking online I found out a solution:

In terminal type:
sudo nano /boot/config.txt

scroll down to:

```
[pi4]

#Enable DRM VC4 V3D driver on top of the dispmanx display stack
```

and comment out:
`dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d`

when done your config should look like this:

```
[pi4]
#Enable DRM VC4 V3D driver on top of the dispmanx display stack

#dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d
```